# Include Child Documents in Elastic Search Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to include child documents into a query with elastic search, but I cannot figure it out. I have an entity called posts that has an optional parent to support a parent child hierarchy. I am hoping to do a query on the parent or top level items and include the top child with the results, preventing doing multiple calls to elastic search.

Mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "post": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "post"
      },
      "id": { "type": "integer"},
      "text": { "type": "string"},
      "parent_id": { "type": "integer"},
      "rank": { "type": "integer"}
    }
  }
}
```

Desired Response

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 10,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "test",
        "parent_id": null,
        "rank": 10,
        "topResponse": {
          "id": 2,
          "text": "test response",
          "parent_id": null,
          "rank": 4
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "test 2",
        "parent_id": null,
        "rank": 8,
        "topResponse": {
          "id": 2,
          "text": "test response",
          "parent_id": null,
          "rank": 3
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "test 3",
        "parent_id": null,
        "rank": 6,
        "topResponse": {
          "id": 2,
          "text": "test response",
          "parent_id": null,
          "rank": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```